# Query DB for first or last name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm working on a search feature for my users table so that I can query a user and display it in my app. So far I have it working for first_name but I'm unsure of the syntax to use to also search last name in the same query. My users controller looks like this:

```
  def search
   if params[:search].blank?
    redirect_to users_path and return
  else
   @parameter = params[:search].downcase
   @results = User.all.where("lower(first_name) LIKE :search", search: "%#{@parameter}%")
 end
end
```

Output:

```
User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (lower(first_name) LIKE '%laura%')
```

My search form looks like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <%= search_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Type ", class: "form-control" %>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <%= button_tag "Search User", class: "btn btn-info", :name => nil %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And my results page:

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td><%= link_to result.full_name, user_path(result) %></td>
       <td><%= result.email %></td>
       <td><% if result.subscribed? %>
       <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success">Subscribed</span>
         <% else %>
       <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">Not Subscribed</span>
     <% end %>
```

This works perfect however I'd like to be able to put a last_name and display those results.
I know I'm close but a few things I've tried has not worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try changing

```
@results = User.all.where("lower(first_name) LIKE :search", search: "%#{@parameter}%")
```

into

```
@results = User.all.where("lower(first_name) LIKE :search or lower(last_name) LIKE :search", search: "%#{@parameter}%")
```

Please do and update...

R

Comment: This worked perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On Postgres you can use `ILIKE` to perform a case insensive match:

```
def search
  @term = params[:search]
  redirect_to users_path and return unless @term.present?
  @users = User.where(
    'users.first_name ILIKE :term OR users.last_name ILIKE :term', 
    term: "%#{@term}%"
  )
end
```